# 80's or maybe early 90's movie, nuclear wasteland, bunch of people in a truck driving through the desert

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

Can't remember any of the actors, basically this group of people led by some muscular guy, if I remember correctly, are traveling in a truck driven by him, in the desert of a post-apocalyptic wasteland, towards a specific destination.

What I remember is that there's an Asian man who has some kind of (electronic) device that can save their lives (maybe?), and that when traveling though the desert they encounter some kind of "heat lightning" that require them to wear a mask/sunglasses and that they have to unload the water tank above their truck to lower the temperature inside the truck itself temporarily... has anyone seen it?

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [Neon City](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0104981/) from 1991. The Asian man you're referring to is "Wing" who turns out to be a scientist. The 'heat lighting' is something called a "Bright". They resolve the heat issue by blowing the water seals over the truck.

> "Mad Max" clone set in the not-too-distant future about a group of
>   people trying to escape to a safe haven called Neon City after a solar
>   disaster that has decimated the Earth.