# 2010s (?) movie, possibly German, where everyone is hiding from sunlight

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I saw the trailer maybe 6-8 years ago.  May have been a German language movie - the trailer was in English.

Post-apocalyptic.  People hiding from very harsh sunlight. Kind of *Mad Max*.

Comment: [Neon City?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158977/80s-or-maybe-early-90s-movie-nuclear-wasteland-bunch-of-people-in-a-truck-dr/158978#158978)

Comment: Nosferatu. You did say 1922, right? ;-)

Comment: It might be [Riddick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98I5LTPcRnw) from 2013

Answer (score 27):

Sounds like *Hell* (2011), a German movie directed by Tim Fehlbaum.

From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/hell_2011/):

> As the sun scorches the Earth, threatening to wipe out all life on the planet, desperate survivors Philip, Marie, and her younger sister Leonie race to reach a water reservoir rumored to be nestled deep in the mountains. Making the acquaintance of a lone mechanic named Tom as they head towards the mountains in a specially outfitted car, the trio must fight for their lives after being drawn into an ambush.

Comment: [English-dubbed trailer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w50uKhDNUlc). In my humble opinion, the German original sounds better so it's the one which will stay in the answer. And for what it's worth, this is a _great_ unknown movie.

Comment: Thank you - this is it: Hell (2011), a German movie directed by Tim Fehlbaum

Comment: By the way, "hell" means "bright" in German, but obviously a German audience will also be familiar with the english word "hell", so this is a pretty clever title for the setting of the movie.

Comment: Huh this looks rather good